# How to output data on to a CSV file, after extracting data from XML file using LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, export-to-csv

I have an XML schema file, and I am trying to pull the attribute values for each of the element, that is in this XMl Schema file.

Comment: Samuel as posted this question a number of times.  Code above works.  It appears that his project may be missing some references.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error. You are writing the `csv` object for every line, instead of `line`.

Additionally, you can restructure the writing logic as such:

```
using (StreamWriter writeToFile = new StreamWriter(@"igxSpec.csv"))
{
    foreach (string line in csv)
    {
        writeToFile.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

This makes it a little cleaner, and automatically does the cleanup after `StreamWriter` is done writing the content to file.

Comment: @Hi Den, but it’s still doesn’t fix my issue. I am still not able to output the values of type,label, compType, readonly, hidden, and  required,  for each element onto a CSV file.

Comment: @Samuel how do you envision that working, given that your elements are wildly inconsistent? Not every element has the same values and parameters.

Comment: so you mean to say it’s not possibly to pull the data from elements because they aren’t consistent?

Comment: @Samuel it is possible, but it's unclear what your logic should be - do you want it to be empty? Have a placeholder value?